# Probability of mutual exclusive

Tags: probability

[image]

- A. The quantity in Column A is greater
- B. The quantity in Column B is greater
- C. The two quantities are equal
- D. The relationship cannot be determined from the information given
  Which will be the answer?

I have evaluated the probability for **Quantity  A**  which is $ (3/5)(2/4)=3/10$
which is same as for  **Quantity B**. So the answer would be C.

But the answer is given B because of Mutual exclusive.

I really dont understand hee the mutual exclusive terms :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two events are mutually exclusive if they cannot occur at the same time. So, for quantity B, our probability is going to be either picking RW or WR (e.g. RW means picking a red marble, then a white marble)- as these events are mutually exclusive, we calculate the individual probabilities and then add to get the final probability. In this case the probability is $$(3/5)\times(2/4) + (2/5) \times (3/4) = 6/10$$ so the answer to the question is B.

Comment: If we say we have to pick red first then the answer will be $C$?

Comment: @mathphy Yes - if the order in which we had to pick the marbles was specified, then the answer would have been $C$.

Answer (score 2):

USe law of total probability. Denote $S$ the event $R_1 R_2$ and $S'$ the event $R_1W_2 \cup R_2 W_1$:
$$
P(S)=P(S|R_1)P(R_1)+P(S|W_1)P(W_1)=\frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{4} + 0\\
P(S')=P(S'|R_1)P(R_1)+P(S'|W_1)P(W_1)=\frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{5}\cdot \frac{2}{4}>P(S)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Think of the case B as two separated cases then add them afterwards.

1 - You'll have 3/5 of chance of getting the red first, then 2/4 of getting the white one. This is the case where you got red first.
2 - If you get white first, you'll have 2/5 then 3/4 to get the red one.

If you add them, you'll have 6/10 to get answer B.

To check it's correct, calculate the chance of getting all whites:
2/5 * 1/4 which is 1/10.

The total sum of probabilities in one event needs to be 100%, or one. If you sum the three cases, you'll get 1 as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ possible outcomes.

There are $\binom{3}{2}=3$ outcomes with two red marbles.  Hence $$\mathrm{Pr}[\text{two red marbles}]=\frac{3}{10}.$$

There are $\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}=6$ outcomes with one red marble and one white marble.  Hence $$\mathrm{Pr}[\text{one red marble and one white marble}]=\frac{6}{10}.$$

There are $\binom{2}{2}=1$ outcome with two white marbles.  Hence $$\mathrm{Pr}[\text{two white marbles}]=\frac{1}{10}.$$